# Is this function one-to-one or onto?

Tags: functions

Let $c:P(\mathbb{N})\to\mathbb{Z}$ be the function defined by $c(X)=−1$ if $X$ is empty and $c(X)=\min_{x\in X} x$ if $X$ is not empty.

Is $c(X)$ one to one? Explain.

I have asked this question previously but I could not quite understand the answer. If a function is one-to one then it means that if$f(X)=f(Y)$, then $X=Y$ right? So in the case of this question how do I understand if it is one-to-one or not? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A function is one-to-one if it is injective, which means that each element of codomain has a unique pre-image (and since the function must be defined everywhere in its domain, it follows that the domain is in one-to-one correspondence with the _range_ of $f$).

Answer (score 3):

$$c(\{1,2\})=c(\{1,3\})=1$$ so it is **not** one-to-one because it maps two different sets to the same point. It is also not onto because $c(X)\geq -1$ and so there is no set it maps to $-2$

Comment: Who down-vote this answer? Can s/he give a reason?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you got c({1,2})=c({1,3})?

Comment: @Stella, if you want, you can add something a bit more about well-defined part of the function.

Comment: @SAR they both have the same smallest element, $1$

Comment: Come on @SAR :) It is the definition of $c$. It turns to the minimum value in the set.

Comment: I understand c({1,2})=c({1,3}) has the same answer 1. So It isn't one-to-one since c({1,2})=1 instead of {1,2}?

Comment: No, it's not one-to-one because there are different units that give the same output

Comment: Ahh i think i get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the domain of $c$ is the _power set_ of the naturals, hence it takes subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ as inputs. It's outputs are integers.

Comment: NB: I meant to say inputs not units in my most recent comment. Autocorrect strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

Let the Naturals start with $0$.

First of all, since any subset of $\mathbb N$ has a minimal element and it is (of-course) unique. Therefore, function is well-defined.

Secondly: if $0 \in X$, then $f(X)=0$ since $0$ is the minimal element of any subset of $\mathbb N$ which includes $0$. Since there are infinitely many subset of $\mathbb N$ which includes $0$. It can't be one-to-one.

Thirdly, if $X \not= \emptyset$, then $\min X \in \mathbb N$. Hence image can be subset of $\mathbb N \cup \{-1\}$. Moreover, $c(\{a\})=a$ for every $a \in \mathbb N$. Therefore image of $c$ is $\mathbb N \cup \{-1\}$.